Multiple .env for local and testing environments
I'm pretty new to the Spring Boot spring-dotenv plugin. I am using the .env for local testing, but I want to use a custom .env file .env.testing on my testing environment that has different credentials and configurations.
Is there a way to tell the spring-dotenv plugin using mvn spring-boot:run command to initialize a different .env file?
I keep both of my .env files inside the src/main/resources directory:
src/main/resources/
 .env
 .env.testing
 application.yml


Try adding .env.properties in src/main/resources and add prefix=env. to see if this works.

I did but all it does is sets a different name prefix, how do I then change it on run as part of the command line startup?

@Alex Which version of spring boot are you using?

Spring boot 3.0.6 and Spring core 6.0.8

@Alex Let me test it.I will get back to you if possible.

You can use profiles here and same can be configured in your application yaml file.
So when you use below command with testing profile it’ll activate test environment.
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=testing

Application yaml file:
Spring:
  profiles:
    active: default
  dotenv: 
    filenames: 
      default: .env
      testing: .env.testing


I tried your recommended approach via the application.yml file and it doesn't work

Please add this dependency and try this again.  
io.github.cdimascio
dotenv-spring-boot-starter
5.3.4


the following artifact "dotenv-spring-boot-starter" doesn't exist, where did you find it? is it maybe a custom package that I need to build by downloading from github?

If you prefer, you can create a Maven profile in your pom.xml to handle different environments. Add a profile for testing:
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.dotenv.path>src/main/resources/.env.testing</spring.dotenv.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

Then, you can activate the profile with:
mvn spring-boot:run -Ptest


I tried through the pom.xml as you suggested and it doesn't work, defaults to the .env file by default and doesn't want to try to hit it. I also tried to use a full path vs relative path and still the same.
